# Ignoring "Created By" and "Modified By" Columns in list search results

Tags: 2013, list, search

In our SharePoint, we have a contact list, in which, I created an item for every employee. 
The problem is now, when someone is searching for me, every item appears in the search result page, because I created them.

Is there a way to configure this "list search", that it won't display any items in which the search term matches the columns "Created By" or "Modified By"?

Comment: Are you using Foundation or Server?

Comment: Server Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

I changed the Additional Column Settings from these two collumns to "User name" instead of "Name (with presence)" and now it works for my case.

Comment: Just curious, why keep a second list when you have User Profiles and People Search?

Comment: Good question.. Never asked that myself :-) We had a contact list before in Excel, which entries I just copied to SharePoint.

Comment: OK, if it's just a list of users, you already have that and it's kept updated in the User Profile Service (if the Service is set up correctly).

Comment: Please add more details how you solved it.